# "devenv" command is not recognized

Tags: visual-studio-2013, devenv

I have downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2013 Express (from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop))
When i try to run the command devenv I get an error - 
[image]

Comment: Most likely it's just not in your `PATH` environment variable. Have you tried starting it from the Start menu/screen icon?

Comment: `devenv` is the name of the VS Professional process. VS Express is named differently but since I don't have it installed, I don't have it handy.